# How to detect collision from a text file

Tags: c#, winforms, 2d-games

I am creating a pacman game where the map is read in from a file(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfuaa.jpg) and painted(just a breif example of the things i need to be detecting collision with):

```
case 'h': //horizontal line
          //create solid brush
          //brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, x * cellSize, y * cellSize + cellSize / 2 - 1, cellSize, 3);
    break;
case 'v': //vertical line
          //create solid brush
          //brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
    g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, x * cellSize + cellSize / 2 - 1, y * cellSize, 3, cellSize);
    break;
```

I am then getting a pacman image from file. I am able to move it about at the moment but I am not sure how to go about checking if it collides with one of the walls.

I have thought about creating a rectangle for the pacman image and then trying to compare it with the case statements I have but after that I am not too sure what to do.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Kepp Your textfile (may be in an 2-dimensional array) as a reference. Calculate Pacmans position in this textfile by the cells width and height and lookup the character. If it's an h or v Pacman has hit a wall.